# An error about Dataset.filter in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to filter the dataset only to contain the record which can be found in MySQL.

Here is the Dataset:

```
dataset.show()
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  3|    c|
+---+-----+
```

And here is the table in MySQL:

```
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  3|    c|
|  4|    d|
+---+-----+
```

This is my code (running in spark-shell):

```
import java.util.Properties

case class App(id: Int, name: String)

val data = sc.parallelize(Array((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")))
val dataFrame = data.map { case (id, name) => App(id, name) }.toDF
val dataset = dataFrame.as[App]

val url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/tbl_name"
val table = "my_tbl_name"
val user = "my_user_name"
val password = "my_password"

val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("user", user)
properties.setProperty("password", password)

dataset.filter((x: App) => 
  0 != sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, Array("id = " + x.id.toString), properties).count).show()
```

But I get "java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.getConf(SQLConf.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf.defaultDataSourceName(SQLConf.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:623)
```

I have tested

```
val x = App(1, "aa")
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, Array("id = " + x.id.toString), properties).count

val y = App(5, "aa")
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, Array("id = " + y.id.toString), properties).count
```

and I can get the right result 1 and 0.

What's the problem with filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the problem with filter?

You get an exception because you're trying to execute an action (`count` on a `DataFrame`) inside a transformation (`filter`). Neither nested actions nor transformations are supported in Spark.

Correct solution is as usual either `join` on compatible data structures, lookup using local data structure or query directly against external system (without using Spark data structures).